# PHP $_GET запрос

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, get

Привет

```
index.php

$rs = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($rs);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo '<a href="user?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['login'].'</a>';
     внимание на это ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
    } 


user.php

$rs = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'";
$result = mysql_query($rs);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['login'];
}
```

Итак. Как видно из кода, при нажатии на имя, пользователь перессылает на страницу **user?id=..** 
Но мне не нравится такой вид адреса к человеку: **/user?id=1**.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы например была ссылка не по **id**, а по **$row['login']**?

Например, хочу чтобы ссылка была такая: **/user?login_cheloveka** без никаких **id=..** или **login=login_cheloveka**

Как мне стоит переписать код? В Интернете искал, не нашел решения или не понял.

Comment: ну так поменяй на форме `id` на `login`

Comment: Чтобы такое сделать надо играться уже с htaccess. Смотрите и изучайте его

Comment: если поменять id на login, то получится /user?login=login_cheloveka. А мне хотелось бы /user?login_cheloveka

Comment: @AlievA., почему бы тогда сразу так не сделать: `/user/login_cheloveka`.

Answer (score 2):

> /user?login_cheloveka

Ты не сможешь это сделать без url rewrite. В URI ты передаешь параметры "переменная=значение".  Используй url rewrite.
если тебе нужно в единичном случае и не хочешь заморачиваться, разбирай строку `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, там будет твое имя пользователя